# c# "using" statement follow by try statement can the bracket be ombitted in that case?

Tags: c#, try-catch, using

```
  using System.Net;       // (See Chapter 16)
   ...
  string s = null;
  using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) // why there is no brackets after this using statement
      try { s = wc.DownloadString ("http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/");  }
      catch (WebException ex)
      {
        if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.Timeout)

          Console.WriteLine ("Timeout");
        else
          throw;     // Can't handle other sorts of WebException, so rethrow
      }
```

The above code is copy from Page 153 c# in a Nutshell, I don't understand why the { } are missing after the using statement, is that a typo in the book (unlikely) or just not needed? As the syntax is that using need to follow by a block of code inside {}.

I would expect this code to be:

```
  using System.Net;       // (See Chapter 16)
   ...
  string s = null;
  using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) // why there is no brackets after this using statement
  {
      try { s = wc.DownloadString ("http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/");  }
      catch (WebException ex)
      {
        if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.Timeout)

          Console.WriteLine ("Timeout");
        else
          throw;     // Can't handle other sorts of WebException, so rethrow
      }
  }
```

Comment: We use the block `{ }` to introduce a scope of multiple lines, we don't use them when we want to introduce a scope of a single line like `if(true) return;` In this case the `Try` statement will introduce its own multi-line scope. So it's not required.

Comment: The curly braces are only needed if you have multiple statements you want included.  A try-catch is one statement, so they are not needed, but it's bad form.  And you could technically remove all the curly braces and the code would still function the same way.

Comment: Seems off to me also

Comment: @Mahmoud thanks, but if I add the brackets, there is no side effect right? thanks

Comment: @juharr do you mean it is better to keep the brackets after using statement rather than remove it, right? Thanks.

Comment: @bean In general it's best to use brackets when the statement is more than one line and some would say it's best to always use them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look at the grammar of the `using` statement in the [C# Specification](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/statements.md#the-using-statement), you see that using statements are followed by (or rather, their body consists of) "embedded_statements".

```
using_statement
    : 'using' '(' resource_acquisition ')' embedded_statement
    ;
```

Embedded statements are defined as follows:

```
embedded_statement
    : block
    | empty_statement
    | expression_statement
    | selection_statement
    | iteration_statement
    | jump_statement
    | try_statement
    | checked_statement
    | unchecked_statement
    | lock_statement
    | using_statement
    | yield_statement
    | embedded_statement_unsafe
    ;
```

So yes, this is not a typo. After `using (...)`, there can be any of the statements that are defined in `embedded_statement`. And anyway, to see whether this is a typo, you could have just simply tried to compile the example code.

Answer (score 1):

If the `{}` are omitted the next statement is the statement under the using. In this case that would be the `try` statement.

It's similar to the if statement (or any other):

```
if(x == 0) return; // No {} the next statement is affected by the if
```

`{}` basically groups several statements together turning it into a single statement so basically the same rule applies.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I cannot add anything significant to `Adrian's` great Answer. But I will answers your latest questions about the curly braces:

> but if I add the brackets, there is no side effect right?

No, there is no side effect. Actually your code might end up with a few extra `NOP` instructions in the `IL` code if `Optimization` flag is disabled.
For example this Method:

```
public void CurlyBracesMethod(){
    {
        int r = 1;
        r+=2;
    }
    if(true)
        return;
}
```

Will be represented in the IL as the following [`Optimization` flag is disabled]:

```
  .locals init (int32 V_0,
           bool V_1)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  nop
  IL_0002:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0003:  stloc.0
  IL_0004:  ldloc.0
  IL_0005:  ldc.i4.2
  IL_0006:  add
  IL_0007:  stloc.0
  IL_0008:  nop
  IL_0009:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_000a:  stloc.1
  IL_000b:  br.s       IL_000d
  IL_000d:  ret
```

Whereas, the following method:

```
public void NonCurlyBracesMethod(){
    int r = 1;
    r+=2;
    if(true)
        return;
}
```

Will be represented as the following in the `IL` code:

```
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0002:  stloc.0
  IL_0003:  ldloc.0
  IL_0004:  ldc.i4.2
  IL_0005:  add
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
  IL_0007:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0008:  stloc.1
  IL_0009:  br.s       IL_000b
  IL_000b:  ret
```

> do you mean it is better to keep the brackets after using statement rather than remove it

It depends, in some cases not using the curly brackets might end up in a logical error. For example:

```
for(int i = 1;i<=n;i++){
       if(i%2==0){
         add+=1;
         flg=true;
    }
}
```

If I removed the curly braces from the previous code, `add+=1` will executed only if the condition is satisfied which is true. But the `flg=true` will be executed always. This is a logical error.
Also, you can use `Curly Braces` to introduce new scope as I did in the method `CurlyBracesMethod`. `r` variable will not be seen outside the curly braces and any attempt to reference this variable will end up with a compilation error.
Finally, in most cases, using curly braces is encouraged as it helps making your code more readable and easy to maintain.